# Is it ok if I charge my IPad with the power adapter that I use for my Samsung Tablet?

Tags: battery, power, adapter, ipad

My iPad version details are as follows:

- Model A1460
- Complies with the Canadian ICES-003 Class B specifications
- FCC ID: BCGA1460 and IC: 579C-A1460 Serial: DMPKF3F4F18Y

There is something wrong with my iPad power adapter.

However, I do have a Samsung tablet power adapter with the following electrical specifications:

- MODEL: ETA-U90JWE
- INPUT: 100-240V - 50-60Hz 035A
- OUTPUT: 5.0V --0 2.0A

Can I safely use the aforementioned Samsung tablet power adapter to charge my iPad, or would there be a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for answering the question, and I am sorry about asking the title question in such a way that it is different from the question asked in the paragraph.   In any case,  I wanted to share my experience.  I connected the Samsung power adapter to my iPad using the cable.   It charged extremely slowly despite the iPad contradictory display statement that said "Not Charging."    Therefore,  I had to go to an apple store in order to purchase an actual Apple power adapter for the iPad.

Thanks for inputu

Answer (score 0):

Yes, both have a DC output at 5vDC and can source at least 1.5A, so you are good.

Comment: The question is "Would there be any problem if I use the aforementioned Samsung Tablet power Adapter to charge my IPad?" So, the first word of your answer should be 'NO' since there won't be any problem! :p

Comment: But... But... The title.... There is no answer here...

Comment: The title and the question in the body are contradictory, Can you edit any one of them? @Matt

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it's perfectly fine. They are both USB power adapters.

Comment: Same comment as above :p

Comment: The title question asks if it is okay. I'm am answering that question.

Comment: Yes you are, however if the previous answer answers the question, it probably isn't a good idea to post a duplicate answer - especially when it's not as detailed as the above answer. I won't vote to delete, so it's up to you.

Comment: My answer was first. I could edit it to make it more detailed, but the asker isn't likely to return to this question anyway.